# Email replies from my client's iPad Air have t.signaldue.com links in the source code

Tags: thunderbird, email

When I receive replies from one of my clients who just got a new iPad Air, Thunderbird has a "this may be a scam". When I view the source code of the reply, there are links in the source code that look like this:

```
http://t.signaledue.com/e1t/c/5/f18dQhb230S7lC8dDMPbW2n0x6l2B9nMJW7t5XYg1p7ZyHW7gbJlv7NWM6RF83DGb1NQHQf8yZ_YM03?t=https%3a%2f%2fmydomain.com&si=6488133648515072&pi=39674142-ea34-4987-9ebe-efa86d98d019
```

I have a LinkedIn image in my signature and there is also a similar "`t.signaldue.com`" link.

These only appear in the source code... nothing is visible in the email. I can find nothing on the internet that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the person sending the email is using a CRM app called [Sidekick](http://www.getsidekick.com/).

I discovered this after noticing the same weird URL in some emails so did a little detective work.

If you copy and paste the URL in the email into a browser, but without the query string, you will notice that you get redirected to the following URL:

```
http://api.getsidekick.com/e1t/c/5/f18dQhb230S7lC8dDMPbW2n0x6l2B9nMJW7t5XYg1p7ZyHW7gbJlv7NWM6RF83DGb1NQHQf8yZ_YM03
```